# UIImageView shows the image for first time and then suddenly goes back to the old image in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, image, swift3, uiimageview

I am using a UIImageView to change the image of the user. Currently the user has the option to remove the already present image. For this i am having a  UIButton named "Remove photo" and in the action the code is written as:

```
@IBAction func removeUserPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.profilePhoto.image = UIImage (named: "defaultProfilePic")
    self.photoChanged = true
    let imageData: Data =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePhoto.image!)!
    tempProfileImage = imageData
    self.removePhoto.isHidden = true
   }
```

When I click on the remove image the image is set to the defaultProfilePic but after few seconds the image view again shows the older image which the user has removed.

Note: No API call has been called yet.

The screenshots:

[image: Initial Setup]

After clicking the remove button:

[image]

Few seconds after it again changes back to the older image automatically.

[image]

Why is this happening? And I found viewDidLayoutSubviews is calling twice or more.
I'm using Xcode 8.3 Beta.

Comment: what is the use of this image view `tempProfileImage`

Comment: It is being stored to the userdefaults. It is for Showing the changed image in other screens fast.

Comment: You aren't providing a complete description of your problem. You need to describe the different image views, how they are set up in the storyboard, and post ALL code that shows/hides the different image views. Lion has a good point. It seems like you'd be better off having a single image view that displays the current image. If it's a placeholder, display that, if it's a custom image, display that.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove image something like,

```
  yourImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "your place holder image name")
```

I mean assign your place holder image to your imageview! That's it! No need to take two imageviews!